# Setting value of an element AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate an iframe with using selenium webdriver and have to set a value of text box.
HTML:

```
<input class="ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" 
id="name" type="text" data-ng-model="$parent.card.name" 
maxlength="26" name="cc-name" placeholder="Holder Name" required="">
```

The scope seems like hidden. So, I couldn't find a way to set a value of angular element on iframe using selenium webdriver. Do you have any suggestion about it?

Comment: Did you add `ng-pristine ng-empty` etc to your view? Angular manages this for you (assuming angular is injected into the view).

Answer (score 1):

For Frame element, you can try to switch to frame first and then try to find that element

```
driver.switchTo().frame('frameName');
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually,I was changing the frame. The solution that I found is adding change() event like `$('#name').val('test').change();`